# Sorting UITableView not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, nspredicate

I a sorting system that sorts the data in my array though I have run into troubles while on the brink of completion. I have set up all of the systems to do it though it now tells me I have an error. Here is the offending code snippet and error it gives:

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [[patients filterUsingPredicate:search] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

The error it says is at patients and it says:

```
Bad receiver type void
```

This is the code in context:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static  NSString *cellIndentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIndentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *letter = [charIndex objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
    NSPredicate *search = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"patientName beginswith[cd] %@", letter];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"patientName" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *filteredArray = [[patients filterUsingPredicate:search] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    if ( nil == cell ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    NSLog(@"indexPath.row = %d, patients.count = %d", indexPath.row, patients.count);
    Patient *thisPatient = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", thisPatient.patientName, thisPatient.patientSurname];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    if (self.editing) {
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Is the a thing that happens a lot and if so is there a way round it???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filterUsingPredicate:` is a void method so you can't call methods on its result. Also you don't want to filter this array inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as that will really mess with your data. Every cell you'd discard some of your patients!

Try:

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [[patients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:search] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: How would I do that I am quite new to objective-c. Sorry

Comment: Wait no if I try and delete an item it fails and comes up with the error: `*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1070`

Comment: how is that related to your current question? You should debug, and search on the error; if you can't solve it still, ask a separate question as it seems like a different issue entirely.